# Using PFQuery to retrieve PFInstallation objects containing a specific item in their array?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm trying to send push notifications to users if one of their favorite foods appear on a dining menu on a given day. For example, if a user lists pizza, spaghetti, and potato as his favorite foods, and on a particular day, the menu contains pizza, the user would receive a push notification.

This is how I'm currently storing the favorite foods

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [installation addUniqueObject:foodName forKey:@"favorites"];
    [installation saveInBackground];
```

In the available functions, I found these, but after closer inspection, they don't seem to be what I need

```
- (void)whereKey:(NSString *)key containedIn:(NSArray *)array;
- (void)whereKeyExists:(NSString *)key;
```

(I'll be using cloud code to retrieve the data, but I'm assuming there is an analogous javascript method.)

Is there a way to get a query of all the installation objects containing a given item in their favorites array?

Also, although I map each user to an array of foods, it seems more intuitive to map each food to an array of corresponding users.  However, I don't want users to enter login info, so I'm trying to avoid the PFUser class, and I don't know if there is another way of adding a user to an array.  I'm wondering if this is possible, and if it would make it easier to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation on [Queries on Array Values](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-arrays/iOS), if you want to find rows where a value exists in an array:

```
[query whereKey:@"favorites" equalTo:@"pizza"];
```

This will return all rows where "pizza" is in the array column "favorites".

Comment: Instead of identical matches, if I wanted to check if the favorited word is contained within the food name-- for example, if the user favorites "pizza," they should get a notification for "cheese pizza," "pepperoni pizza," etc -- would I split the food into an array of the individual words and use `whereKey:containedIn:`

Comment: That certainly presents some interesting challenges, sounds worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for [PFRelation](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFRelation.html) Class on Parse.com for relational queries.

and for query you can go for blocks (sorry it's in swift coding)

```
let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
query.whereKey("favorite", containedIn: ["item1", "item2"])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects: AnyObject[]!, error: NSError!) in
      // your code      
})
```